# Python TimedRotatingFileHandler not writing to file

Tags: python

I have a TimedRotatingFileHandler configured and I'm trying to get it to write to a file.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    logger = logging.getLogger('testlog')

    logHandler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename="../logfile.log", when="midnight")
    logHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    logFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    logHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)

    logger.addHandler(logHandler)

    print(logger.handlers)
    logger.info('hello')
```

The file gets created, but my statements aren't getting written. I've tried running this both in the IDE and from the command line.

I also printed logger.handlers and got

```
[<TimedRotatingFileHandler [MY_DIRECTORY]/logfile.log (INFO)>]
```

so I have no idea what's wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was setting the level on the log handler:

```
loggerHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

instead of the Logger

```
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```